# Unable to find vcvarsall.bat, нужна помощь

Tags: python

Имеется Win 7 x64, Python 3.5.1 x64, Visual Studio C++ 2008 Express, vcvarsall.bat находится в директории C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC.

Прописал в PATH эту директорию, создавал в регистре запись productdir, вручную прописывал в msvc9compiler.py в переменную vcvarsall путь как .bat

Ничего не помогает, все равно выскакивает ошибка, что можно с этим сделать?

Comment: возможно действительный вопрос у вас: как установить Питон-пакет X на Windows. Ответ зависит от X, например, не рекомендуется самостоятельно компилировать `numpy`, если вы не знаете `vcvarsall.bat`

Comment: Пытаюсь установить PyCrypto

Comment: `py -mpip install pycryptodome` (возможно `x` на конце)

Comment: https://github.com/sfbahr/PyCrypto-Wheels

Answer (score 1):

## Если вы всё ещё хотите компилировать с Visual Studio C++ вместо того чтобы юзать mingw...

1. Запустите python.exe, чтобы увидеть, с какой версией VC ++ он был скомпилирован (пример показан ниже).

> Важно использовать соответствующую версию компилятора Visual C ++, с
>   которой был скомпилирован Python, так как distilutils's
>   get_build_version предотвращает смешивание версий.

В вашем случае  Python 3.5.1 x64, и Visual Studio C++ 2008 не сочетаются

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

2. Используйте приведенную ниже таблицу, чтобы сопоставить внутреннюю версию VC ++ с соответствующим выпуском Visual Studio:

   `MSC v.1000 -> Visual C++ 4.x        
   MSC v.1100 -> Visual C++ 5          
   MSC v.1200 -> Visual C++ 6          
   MSC v.1300 -> Visual C++ .NET       
   MSC v.1310 -> Visual C++ .NET 2003  
   MSC v.1400 -> Visual C++ 2005  (8.0)
   MSC v.1500 -> Visual C++ 2008  (9.0)
   MSC v.1600 -> Visual C++ 2010 (10.0)
   MSC v.1700 -> Visual C++ 2012 (11.0)
   MSC v.1800 -> Visual C++ 2013 (12.0)
   MSC v.1900 -> Visual C++ 2015 (14.0)
   MSC v.1910 -> Visual C++ 2017 (15.0)
   MSC v.1911 -> Visual C++ 2017 (15.3)
   MSC v.1912 -> Visual C++ 2017 (15.5)
   MSC v.1913 -> Visual C++ 2017 (15.6)
   MSC v.1914 -> Visual C++ 2017 (15.7)
   MSC v.1915 -> Visual C++ 2017 (15.8)
   MSC v.1916 -> Visual C++ 2017 (15.9)`

   3. Загрузите и установите соответствующую версию Visual Studio C ++ из предыдущего шага.

### Примечания для Visual Studio C++ 2015

Если вам не нужна среда разработки Visual Studio, загрузите Visual Studio C++ 2015 Build Tools.

### Примечания для Visual Studio C++ 2017

Если вам не нужна среда разработки Visual Studio, загрузите Build Tools for Visual Studio 2017.

***Примечание:*** Если у вас присутствует 32- и 64-битная установка Python, вы можете использовать virtualenv для создания отдельных сред Python, так что бы использовать ту или другую одновременно, и не возиться с вашим системным путем, чтобы выбрать, какую версию Python использовать.

Вы можете пропустить загрузку пакетного файла вручную (шаги 4-6), скопировав несколько пакетных файлов туда, где Python выполняет поиск, следующим образом вот ответ. Если это не сработает, вот следующие шаги, которые изначально сработали для меня.

4. Откройте `cmd.exe`

Прежде чем вы попытаетесь установить то, что требует расширений C, запускаете следующий пакетный файл для загрузки среды компилятора VC ++ в сессию (то есть переменные среды, путь к компилятору и т.д

***Выполните:***

32-bit Compilers:
***Прим:*** 32-bit Windows установки будут иметь путь `C:\Program Files\` как и ожидалось

```
"c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\Tools\vsvars32.bat"
```

64-bit Compilers:

```
"c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\Tools\vsvars64.bat"
```

***Прим:*** Да, родные 64-битные компиляторы находятся в Program Files (x86). Не спрашивай меня почему.

Кроме того, если вам интересно, в чем разница между vcvars64.bat и vcvarsx86_amd64.bat или, что более важно, в разнице между amd64 и x86_amd64, первые предназначены для встроенных инструментов 64-разрядных компиляторов, а вторые - это 64-разрядные кросс-компиляторы, которые могут запустить на 32-битной установке Windows.

**Update**:
Если по какой-либо причине вы получаете ошибку:`error: ... was unexpected at this time ...`  `...`- это некоторая серия символов, то вам нужно убедиться, что в переменной пути нет никаких посторонних символов, таких как дополнительные кавычки или случайные символы. Пакетный файл не сможет обновить ваш путь к сеансу, если он не может понять его с самого начала.

Если все прошло хорошо, вы должны получить одно из следующих сообщений в зависимости от того, какую версию VC ++ и какую команду вы выполняли:

Для 32-битных инструментов компилятора:

```
Setting environment for using Microsoft Visual Studio 20xx x86 tools.
```

Для 64-битного компилятора:

```
Setting environment for using Microsoft Visual Studio 20xx x64 tools.
```

Теперь снова запустите установку через `python setup.py install` или `pip install pkg-name`

Надеюсь и скрестим пальцы, что планеты сегодня расположены правильно для взаимодействия с VC ++.